# How to sync my git repository on a new computer?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm newbie to git. I have a repository on bitbucket. Now I want to download it on my computer at work and make some changes on the project, then push it again.

First of all I initialized the git on a local directory by this line:

```
$ git init
```

Then I set something configuration:

```
$ git config --global user.name "my name"
$ git config --global user.email my.email@gmail.com
```

Then I've downloaded it like this:

```
$ git clone https://ShafizadehSajad@bitbucket.org/ ...
```

Now I can see the project's files on my local folder. Ok, Good!

Also I made a connection between my repository and my local directory by this command:

```
$ git remote add origin https://ShafizadehSajad@bitbucket.org/ ...
```

Now when I enter `$ git remove -v`, the result will be:

```
origin  https://ShafizadehSajad@bitbucket.org/ ... (fetch)
origin  https://ShafizadehSajad@bitbucket.org/ ... (push)
```

seems good!

---

When I enter this command: `git status`, I'll see all folders/files with red color. Because of that I entered this command:

```
$ git add .
```

Now they are green! Also I wrote a commit for it by this line:

```
$ git commit -m "there isn't any change"
```

And then to sync my local directory with the one on the bitbucket, I entered this line:

```
$ git push origin master
```

But I get this error:

```
$ git push origin master
To https://bitbucket.org/lamtakam/lamtakam.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://ShafizadehSajad@bitbucket.org/lamtakam/lamtakam.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your very first step is wrong:

```
git init
```

This initializes a completely new git repository in your current directory. You don't want that, you want to just clone the existing repository.

What actually happened is that you then cloned the existing repository **inside** the new repository that you initialized in step 1. Nested git repositories are a bit complicated, but the bottom line is that the files appeared red because all the files were new to the **newly initialized git repo** (which is in no way related to the repo you have in bitbucket).

Your current directory tree looks something like this:

```
/htdocs
  /New Folder <--- you initialized the new git repo here
    /lamkatam <--- this is the git repo you cloned
```

Start over by skipping the first step, doing just `git clone` (you probably want to do this in `htdocs` folder). You can also skip setting the remote - when you do a clone, it will automatically set the remote called `origin` and configure it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, in the meantime somebody updated the repository, prior to push you need to integrate your changes:

```
git pull
```

It seems like the changes on remote repository could require some "merging" on your side. If that's true you should change your copy and commit those changes and then execute:

```
git push
```

If in the meantime nobody didn't change the origin repository you should be able to push your changes.

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the master branch? (git status output)

Comment: git log --oneline
git log --oneline

Comment: Nah.. "git log --oneline", "git fetch", "git log --oneline origin/master"

Comment: I see a token plus my last commit: `17e7d9b there isn't any change`

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help you without output from those commands. I suspect somebody rewritten history on remote machine (SHA of commits don't match on your clone and remote repository).

Answer (score 0):

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

You need to update local repository first (sync with remote) then push to remote (`origin`).

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Try `git pull -u origin master` instead `git pull`.

Comment: Ok. Try `git pull origin master`. `-u` is not valid flag for `Pull`, it is for `Push`, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
git push (name of the dir)
```

ex: git push myfolder

Comment: Don't forget to do "cd .." before